# Alternative metaphor to ‘Blank Canvas’

Tags: idioms, metaphors, simile

I’m trying to use a metaphor along the lines of

- something ripe for exploration
- something multifaceted
- something full of many possibilities

Blank canvas roughly fits some of the above, but it’s very common. Are there any other metaphors that similarly fit the criteria?

Comment: A metaphor that covers both 'unexplored' -and- 'multifaceted' might be hard. But good to investigate both and maybe they can be mixed.

Comment: Could you please use this word/phase you're looking for in a sentence?  I think that would help us hone in on exactly what you're looking for.  (And it's also what you're supposed to do for these.  :-) )  Thanks!

Comment: 'ripe for exploration', or ripe for exploitation?  Actually, it sounds like '[ripe for exploitation](https://ludwig.guru/s/ripe+for+exploitation)' is a metaphor that possibly covers your situation.

Comment: "Blank slate" also works, but it's too similar to your original phrase, so not sure it's worth a full answer...

Comment: I don't consider 'blank canvas' adequate for describing these things. The implication with blank canvas is that you're creating something, not discovering.

Answer (score 15):

["Tabula rasa"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tabula%20rasa) is almost an exact translation of "blank canvas" and has a similar meaning. However, it might not fit the rest of what you want. (For example, it doesn't mean "something multifaceted". In fact, "multifaceted" is nearly an antonym of "blank", so that aspect of your question confused me a bit.)

Comment: 'Blank slate' is the same but without Latin words or empiricist philosophy.

Comment: @Mitch What do you mean by "empiricist philosophy"?  Genuinely curious as I haven't used the word "empiricist".

Comment: [Tabula rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa) is also the name for the theory that all knowledge comes from experience or perception - also known as empiricism.

Comment: @mjjf cmbuckley's comment says it. In the philosophical are of epistemology, there are two (generally recognized sides, empiricism and rationalism. Empiricism says that knowledge comes from experience, and Rationalism says that knowledge comes from within. (of course this is oversimplification, it's a mix of both). 'Tabula rasa' is a term used often to describe the situation for Empiricism, starting from nothing, an empty untouched thing which experience 'writes' on.

Comment: Tabula rasa has a negative connotation. You make tabula rasa if you throw everything into trash and start from scratch again.

Comment: @allo Not necessarily; it can have a positive connotation just as easily. For example: "Some Bauhaus instructors used exercises like these to erase bad habits inculcated by the society and the state of the arts. Itten spoke in these terms: he wanted to return students' minds and muscles to a tabula rasa, a blank slate." ([Jame Elkins, "Why Art Cannot Be Taught," University of Illinois Press, 2001, pg. 34](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Why_Art_Cannot_Be_Taught/_CgtD-dZyk4C))

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Maybe the "trash" part was too much. But it's still talking about *returning* the minds to a tabula rasa. I would say a baby's mind is a blank canvas (It never had content before) and after the person learned quite a bit, Itten want's the mind to return to a tabula rasa (after removing all content).

Comment: @allo I don't think that "tabula rasa" necessarily connotes *returning* to a blank slate; as mentioned above, in empiricism "tabula rasa" suggests that the slate is blank to begin with.

Answer (score 11):

This could be described as a ***new frontier***, which very well captures the notion of something unexplored that holds great possibility. It also happens to be a term used in a 1960 speech by John F. Kennedy, describing the many aspects of promise and peril in the coming decade, from scientific to social to political, which gives it an additional connotation of multifaceted-ness that you're looking for.

Comment: I think this best fits all the requirements in the question body.

Answer (score 9):

["Uncharted territory"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/uncharted-vs-unchartered-waters-usage) or "uncharted waters".

> *Uncharted* refers to something not recorded on a map. *Uncharted waters* or *uncharted territory* can refer literally to places not yet explored, but it can also be used figuratively to refer to unfamiliar situations in general.

Comment: Combining this with another answer: _**virgin territory**_.

Comment: If you want to get fancy & Latinize it, ***terra incognita*** would also work.

Answer (score 5):

I'll pick up on  the serious objection that has already been made to this question ([user MarcinMahattan](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/594002/349876)), and I'll take the opposite view that  the OP is rather deficient as regards its title and that the real quest is not expressed in the title but in the body of the post, the title being in need of a  modification. Accordigly, I propose the term "*fresh territories*", which references show to be usable figuratively.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Cambridge_History_of_Classical_Liter/Cg8SOYw9GLAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fresh+territories%22&pg=PA79&printsec=frontcoverhttps://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Cambridge_History_of_Classical_Liter/Cg8SOYw9GLAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fresh+territories%22&pg=PA79&printsec=frontcover)) Their assumptions and the language used to express them are still heroic , although one has a sense at this point of brilliant new singers carrying the old poetical equipment into fresh territories

Answer (score 3):

["Untapped potential"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/untapped-potential) seems to fit your desired meaning including "ripe for exploration" and "full of possibilities"

Example usage from the above Cambridge dictionary link

> To be fair, some of the larger companies have made substantial moves in that direction recently, but there remains **untapped potential**.

Or even just ["untapped"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/untapped) stands on its own fairly well depending on your usage

> If a supply of something valuable is untapped, it is not yet used or taken advantage of

In the above case the "something valuable" is the *potential*, but you could have "untapped territory" or "untapped resources" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Virgin; blue skies; verdant pastures (biblical: [Ezek 34:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%2034:13-15&version=ISV)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This may be the source of the business metaphor [greenfield](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greenfield) "land (such as a potential industrial site) not previously developed or polluted" (in comparison to 'brownfield' which is the same but previously developed.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like ["potter's clay"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/potter%27s+clay), "wet clay" or "fresh clay"? The idea being that this is a lump of material with the potential to be moulded and sculpted into anything.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it seems to fit the expression **uncut gem**, or alternatively **diamond in the rough**. A rough diamond or other gem stone has potential, but it needs to be cut (which can be done in a variety of ways) to reveal its beauty and value. A cut diamond is obviously multi-faceted, but it has all kinds of applications, such as drill bits and record player needles, so it's multi-faceted in its use too.

Answer (score 1):

The desired tone is unspecified (e.g., technical, formal, poetic, colloquial)... These might also apply:  "clean slate", "new horizon(s)", "virgin territory", "open field", "spring of possibilities", "untapped well", "bucket to be filled", "banquet table"... "bag of cats" ;-).

Answer (score -1):

Personally I like "an unwritten page".